# C# "Persistent" call to DLL

Tags: c#, dll, programming-languages, event-handling

I am calling a method from a self made DLL. This method triggers an event and it is raised by an EventHander inside the class.

The problem is that the control of the execution returns to the main program (WebClass in the diagram) which makes the call to the class before the eventhandler is able to catch the event.

Here is a little diagram of how it should work
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/model1.png

And this is what it actually does
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/model2.png

Is there a way to make the call to the class' method and make sure it will execute all tasks before returning control to the caller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to see what it happening inside your other DLL. By default, it should work as you want. Unless you do something to make it asynchronous, events in .NET are synchronous. When you fire an event, the code that fires that event will not continue to execute until all delegates that are listening to the event have been executing to completion (or one of the delegates throws an exception).

Saying that the code "waits" until the delegates are finished executing isn't even an accurate statement, an event can be thought of as a collection of delegates, and when an event is fired, it loops through all of the delegates and executes them one at a time.

Comment: @Brian thanks... the problem is that the Delegates and Events are defined inside a class y reference from Class2 that is not accesible... All I have is access to are three methods (in Class2 in the diagram). Two of them perform an action (fingerprint scanning) and as they finish an event is triggered and raised by the EventHandler (which belongs to the "outter" class).
If I run this from a simple form it works.. The problem is that I am calling the two "action" methods from inside a "Listen HTTP Request" method.. I guess the problem is that the processing of the HTTP Request runs to fast...

Comment: ...and then the EventHandler doesn't have the chance to capture the event triggered by the action.
So I am trying to find a way to reference or call the methods in Class2 that will assure that all processes will be completed before returning control to WebClass...
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the drivers of the device are what is causing this to work asynchronously, which isn't too surprising. It is more challenging to do this on a website, or anything that acts like a website. Your best bet might be sleep the thread in a loop and check for completion (you will need some sort of semaphore for this). It's not pretty, but you may not have another choice.

Comment: That is exactly what I am suspecting... the problem then is that I am not sure how to implement the Semaphore.. I will do some Googleing and see what I come up with...
Thanks

Comment: @Brian Hi... You were right... I didn't use a semaphore, but AutoResetEvent (WaitOne and Set after the event completed) and it worked. Now I have one more problem...

One of the methods that I call needs to use an object that apparently has been "frozen" in the main thread when calling WaitOne() method.

Is there a way to create that object as some sort of "persistent across threads", or to make it available for the second thread while the main thread is waiting for the event execution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Brian... never mind, I was able to handle it a different way... Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

In your Method1 you wait for the event to be set. And in your event handler E_DataEvent you are setting the signal.

Comment: Thanks... the problem is that if I do `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne();` inside my Method1, the execution stops there... and the event is not raised.